# SCV in a renamed sandbox cant get reconnected

Tags: sandbox-refresh, aws, service-cloud-voice

Some lambdas are failing to run in my SCV AWS connect environment

I have followed the instructions found here https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-salesforce-scv/tree/master/Common/AWSSCV-SalesforceConfig that seem to match the configuration left by the previous intagrator. I am now seeing are error in AWS when running the last test

```
{
"Status": "FAILURE",
"Reason": "Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm."
}
```

I do have a ticket open with SF but if I can find the answer I may be closer to a fix than I am now